# datejs doesn't seem to work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, datejs

I tried to use datejs in Chrome but it doesn't seem to work properly.

Is there any workaround to this issue if I still want to use this lib?

If not, is there any excellent date lib i could use?

Thanks.

I downloaded the full version of datejs from https://code.google.com/p/datejs/downloads/list and found the test included can work well in Chrome.

Then I am very confused why it can't work in chrome for my project.

Here is my code snippet

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<script src="js/date.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
console.log(Date.today());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I got an error message when I run this snippet in Chrome and FireFox

**TypeError: Date.today is not a function**

Comment: What do you mean with _it doesn't seem to work properly_? Maybe you are doing something wrong?

Comment: I am not quite sure...the same code can be executed in IE but not in Chrome

Comment: try jsfiddle and see it works?

Answer (score 1):

I run a much updated and maintained version of DateJS here: https://github.com/abritinthebay/datejs/

I'd strongly recommend switching to it as it has a lot of major bugs fixed and new features.

It certainly *does* work in Chrome (even the original did). If you're getting no `Date.today` function then the code isn't being loaded at all as it's part of the core. Are you sure you're linking the code correctly in that script tag?

Try opening up Chrome's dev console and finding that script tag - then right click on the url and chose "Open In New Tab". If the code doesn't display - there is your problem.

Answer (score -1):

What about [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com)? I think it's the most popular date library for javascript, has been around for quite some time now. It includes a lot of utilities, and also dedicated support for Timezones.